# Relationship in linear dependence between a matrix and its square

Tags: linear-algebra

If a real-valued matrix $X_{m,n}$ has linearly dependent rows/columns, is  $X^{T}X$ guaranteed to be singular? I'm sure about linearly dependent columns case, but not so much about rows case, does the same logic apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any two matrices $A,B$ such that the product $AB$ is defined, the rank satisfies the following inequality:
\begin{align}
\text{rank}(AB) \leq \text{min} (\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(B)).
\end{align}
Also, in general, if $X$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, then

- $\text{rank}(X^t) = \text{rank}(X)$

In your particular case, choose $A= X^t$, and $B= X$. If $X$ has linearly dependent columns, then $\text{rank}(X) < n$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\text{rank}(X^tX) \leq \min(\text{rank}(X^t),\text{rank}(X)) = \text{rank}(X) < n.
\end{align}
Since $X^tX$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, the above inequality in particular shows that $X^tX$ does not have full rank. Hence, it is not invertible.

---

**Edit:**

Since we're working entirely over $\Bbb{R}$, one can show that $\text{rank}(X^tX) = \text{rank}(X)$. From this it follows that $X^tX$ is singular if and only if $X$ has linearly dependent columns.

To prove this, note that by rank-nullity theorem, it suffices to prove that $\ker(X^tX) = \ker(X)$. The inclusion $\ker(X) \subset \ker(X^tX)$ is obvious. Next, suppose $\xi \in \ker(X^tX)$. Then, we have that
\begin{align}
0 &= \langle 0, \xi \rangle \\
&=\langle X^tX  \xi, \xi \rangle \\
&= \langle X \xi, X \xi \rangle
\end{align}
Since the standard inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is positive-definite, it follows that $X \xi = 0$; i.e $\xi \in \ker(X)$. This proves $\ker(X^tX) = \ker(X)$.

Comment: While I don't see an apparent problem with this logic, we have another clearly contradicting answer from a reputable member, so I'll wait for further input for now.

Comment: Not so sure about the $rank(X^{T}X) ≤ rank(X)$ claim

Comment: @AlwaysRightNeverLeft No, that is right. I was a bit hasty in the final strict inequality regarding the min. I have corrected it, and now it agrees with the other answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but could you expand the answer to show that the case of linearly dependent rows with linearly independent columns would result in a full rank  $X^{T}X$ matrix? It is not immediately obvious to me in the current state.

Comment: You might mention that this shows that $X^TX$ is singular _if and only if_ the columns of $X$ are dependent.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've proven the if part, but the converse isn't immediate to me in general. If we assume that we're working entirely over $\Bbb{R}$ rather than an arbitrary field, then I think I have a proof that $\text{rank}(X^tX) = \text{rank}(X)$, and hence the if and only if statement. But if you have a proof in general, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I did specifically mention that $X$ is a real-valued matrix.

Comment: @AlwaysRightNeverLeft My bad for some reason I completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

$X^TX$ will be a singular matrix if and only if the **columns** of $X$ are linearly dependent. If the rows of $X$ are linearly dependent but the columns of $X$ are independent, then $X^TX$ will be non-singular.

Comment: Did you mean dependent in your first sentence?

Comment: @AlwaysRightNeverLeft yes